# Is there a better way to check one string is a substr of another one in Python?

Tags: python

```
   str1 = str1.lower()
   str2 = str2.lower() 
   if str1 != str2 and str1 in str2:
       print('Yes')
```

Is there a better way compared to the code above, to check str1 is a substring of str2, but str1 not the same as str2?

Comment: Nope, that is the most straight forward way to check that pair of conditions

Comment: You could use `:=` to get rid of the first two lines, at the expense of a longer `if` line: `if (str1 := str1.lower()) != (str2 := str2.lower()) and str1 in str2:`

Comment: When you can read aloud your code and it sounds like you would say it in English, that's the better way, at least in Python. What do you mean by "better"? Faster?

Comment: Python warlus operator - `:=`  is convenient in this case but only available after Python 3.8.